# How to increment/decrement the quantity of one item out of a list of items in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: image of error in web app preview]

When I click the increment button, it increments the quantity of all items as shown in image. I need to increment(or decrement) the value of only one item per increment(or decrement) button click. Here is the sample code I tried:

in html:

```
<mat-grid-tile  *ngFor="let oneItem of allItems">
     <td>{{oneItem.itemName}}</td>
     <button (click)="incrementQuantity(oneItem)">
</mat-grid-tile>
```

in ts file:

```
quantity : number =0; //global
.
.
.

incrementQuantity(oneItem: OneItem){
    this.quantity=this.quantity+1;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It seems that 'quantity' is a single var in your ts, so whenever you increment/decrement the quantity, all items read from the same var. I guess you might want to add 'quantity' field to OneItem, then increment oneItem.quantity, or make an array of quantities and tie each element/quantity to allItems[i], depending on your needs. It would help if you show the OneItem structure.

Comment: your quantity variable is gloabal that means when you increment one item it will apply all of them. Can you share your oneItem model. if it has a quantity field you should increase it. If it doesnt have create one

Comment: your code do exactly what you wrote, increments the quantity of all items. As suggested add quantity property to OneItem so you can increment value of only one item.